# Putting Logic in a CoreData Model

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I’m new to iOS development and am working on a language flashcard application where a flashcard is presented to the user and the user can then say if they remembered it or not. If they tap yes, then the card is scheduled to return in the future sometime depending on various variables, if they click no, then the card is scheduled to come back pretty soon. (Spaced Repetition System)

My question is, **where would be a good place to put this scheduling logic when I’m using CoreData** as the storage for the application?

The two places I have thought of are:

*In the subclass of the NSManagedObject for the flashcard.*

For example, I could do something like:

```
Flashcard : NSManagedObject {
    ...
    @NSManaged var nextReview: NSDate?
    func reschedule() {
    // logic to assign a new date to nextReview
    }
    ...
}
```

and then in the controller, which has access to both CoreData (Model) and the View I could simply write:

```
// When the user has tapped a response:
flashcard.reschedule()
```

One upside to this approach I can see is I wouldn't have to rewrite the scheduling logic if I have to assign a new date in a different controller.

or:

*Calculate the new date in the controller and then update the model.*

```
FlashcardViewController {
    ...
    // When the user has tapped on a response:
    let newReviewDate = scheduler.calculateNextReviewDate(...)
    flashcard.nextReview = newReviewDate
}
```

Should the rescheduling logic be something that the controller should be in charge of, or is it something that the model should do. Or should the CoreData NSManagedObject just be the data with validating getters and setters? Is there a way that is preferred in iOS development?

I guess when it comes down to it, I want to know whether or not an NSManagedObject subclass should be managing its own logic.

As an additional, but related question, this type of thing, deciding on which way to organise the code seems to be a weak point for me. Are there any good resources that I can read to learn more about these kinds of decisions and more importantly, when and why it would be good/bad to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the logic in the model, for the reasons that you mentioned.

However, rather than putting it directly in the subclass of NSManagedObject, I would make a category for it, e.g. `FlashCard+Schedule.swift`. This way, on top of the advantages that you stated, if you want to regenerate the model, all the logic will still be there in a separate file.

Edit: Here's a good [article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.g7638d3ro) covering this topic (architecture patterns) in a higher level.

Comment: Thank you. That article especially answers a lot of questions I had!

Comment: Your welcome! Please accept the answer if you feel it helped. Cheers!

Comment: New in xCode 7 you do not need to create categories ( extensions in swift) as xCode will do it for you which will have your properties only. And you can put your logic in your manged object

Answer (score 0):

Neither the model nor the controller. This is called a business logic. Business logic should be in a separate class that does only that (Single Responsibility). I would rather go with having a service class that does the business logic and leave the Model as simple storage and the controller for formatting the model to the UI/view.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion because I have written such an app in Swift recently.

My solution was to have a **memory score** stored with each card, updating it whenever it was marked as "correct" or "incorrect" (and I allowed "no reaction" as well).

The logic of which card to pick next was in a `Dealer` singleton that could rely on these scores to make a good choice with or without a random element. In fact, the algorithm was so simple that it coud very well have been part of the "dealing" view controller.